# I develop an earthquake detector but when it detects a movement, the alarm doesn't stop from ringing

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, accelerometer, buzzer

This is the code that I used. Actually, I use to code: for Arduino sofware and processing IDE software.

Arduino Source Code/Program:

```cpp
#include<LiquidCrystal.h> // lcd Header
LiquidCrystal lcd(7,6,5,4,3,2); // pins for LCD Connection

#define buzzer 12 // buzzer pin
#define led 13 //led pin

#define x A0 // x_out pin of Accelerometer
#define y A1 // y_out pin of Accelerometer
#define z A2 // z_out pin of Accelerometer

/*variables*/
int xsample=0;
int ysample=0;
int zsample=0;
long start;
int buz=0;

/*Macros*/
#define samples 50
#define maxVal 20 // max change limit
#define minVal -20 // min change limit
#define buzTime 5000 // buzzer on time

void setup()
{
    lcd.begin(16,2); //initializing lcd
    Serial.begin(9600); // initializing serial
    delay(1000);
    lcd.print("EarthQuake ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Detector ");
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Calibrating.....");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Please wait...");
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    buz=0;
    digitalWrite(buzzer, buz);
    digitalWrite(led, buz);
    for(int i=0;i<samples;i++) // taking samples for calibration
    {
        xsample+=analogRead(x);
        ysample+=analogRead(y);
        zsample+=analogRead(z);
    }

    xsample/=samples; // taking avg for x
    ysample/=samples; // taking avg for y
    zsample/=samples; // taking avg for z

    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Calibrated");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Device Ready");
    delay(1000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print(" X Y Z ");
}

void loop()
{
    int value1=analogRead(x); // reading x out
    int value2=analogRead(y); //reading y out
    int value3=analogRead(z); //reading z out

    int xValue=xsample-value1; // finding change in x
    int yValue=ysample-value2; // finding change in y
    int zValue=zsample-value3; // finding change in z

    /*displying change in x,y and z axis values over lcd*/
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(xValue);
    lcd.setCursor(6,1);
    lcd.print(yValue);
    lcd.setCursor(12,1);
    lcd.print(zValue);
    delay(100);

    /* comparing change with predefined limits*/
    if(xValue < minVal || xValue > maxVal || yValue < minVal
            || yValue > maxVal || zValue < minVal || zValue > maxVal)
    {
        if(buz == 0)
            start=millis(); // timer start
        buz=1; // buzzer / led flag activated
    }
    else if(buz == 1) // buzzer flag activated then alerting earthquake
    {
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Earthquake Alert ");
        if(millis()>= start+buzTime)
            buz=0;
    }
    else
    {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print(" X Y Z ");
    }

    digitalWrite(buzzer, buz); // buzzer on and off command
    digitalWrite(led, buz); // led on and off command

    /*sending values to processing for plot over the graph*/
    Serial.print("x=");
    Serial.println(xValue);
    Serial.print("y=");
    Serial.println(yValue);
    Serial.print("z=");
    Serial.println(zValue);
    Serial.println(" $");
}
```

Processing IDE Code/Program:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
PFont f6,f8,f12,f10;
PFont f24;
Serial myPort; // The serial port
int xPos = 0; // horizontal position of the graph
float y1=0;
float y2=0;
float y3=0;

void setup ()
{
    // set the window size: and Font size
    f6 = createFont("Arial",6,true);
    f8 = createFont("Arial",8,true);
    f10 = createFont("Arial",10,true);
    f12 = createFont("Arial",12,true);
    f24 = createFont("Arial",24,true);
    size(1200, 700);

    // List all the available serial ports
    println(Serial.list());
    myPort = new Serial(this, "COM10", 9600);
    println(myPort);
    myPort.bufferUntil('\n');
    background(80);
}

void draw ()
{
    serial();
}

void serial()
{
    String inString = myPort.readStringUntil('$'); // reading incomming date from serial
    if (inString != null)
    {
        // extracting all required values of all three axis:
        int l1=inString.indexOf("x=")+2;
        String temp1=inString.substring(l1,l1+3);
        l1=inString.indexOf("y=")+2;
        String temp2=inString.substring(l1,l1+3);
        l1=inString.indexOf("z=")+2;
        String temp3=inString.substring(l1,l1+3);

        //mapping x, y and z value with graph dimensions
        float inByte1 = float(temp1+(char)9);
        inByte1 = map(inByte1, -80,80, 0, height-80);
        float inByte2 = float(temp2+(char)9);
        inByte2 = map(inByte2,-80,80, 0, height-80);
        float inByte3 = float(temp3+(char)9);
        inByte3 = map(inByte3,-80,80, 0, height-80);
        float x=map(xPos,0,1120,40,width-40);

        //ploting graph window, unit
        strokeWeight(2);
        stroke(175);
        Line(0,0,0,100);
        textFont(f24);
        fill(0,00,255);
        textAlign(RIGHT);
        xmargin("EarthQuake Graph (SESMIOGRAPH)",200,100);

        fill(100);
        strokeWeight(100);
        line(1050,80,1200,80);

        strokeWeight(1);
        textAlign(RIGHT);
        fill(0,0,255);
        String temp="X:"+temp1;
        Text(temp,100,95);

        fill(0,255,0);
        temp="Y:"+temp2;
        Text(temp,100,92);

        fill(255,0,0);;
        temp="Z:"+temp3;
        Text(temp,100,89);


        //ploting x y and z values over graph
        strokeWeight(2);
        int shift=40;

        stroke(0,0,255);
        if(y1 == 0)
            y1=height-inByte1-shift;
        line(x, y1, x+2, height-inByte1-shift) ;
        y1=height-inByte1-shift;

        stroke(0,255,0);
        if(y2 == 0)
            y2=height-inByte2-shift;
        line(x, y2, x+2, height-inByte2-shift) ;
        y2=height-inByte2-shift;

        stroke(255,0,0);
        if(y2 == 0)
            y3=height-inByte3-shift;
        line(x, y3, x+2, height-inByte3-shift) ;
        y3=height-inByte3-shift;

        xPos+=1;

        if (x >= width-30) // go back to begining
        {
            xPos = 0;
            background(80);
        }
    }
}

void Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    float xx1=map(x1,0,100,40,width-40);
    float xx2=map(x2,0,100,40,width-40);
    float yy1=map(y1,0,100,height-40,40);
    float yy2=map(y2,0,100,height-40,40);

    line(xx1,yy1,xx2,yy2);
    xx2=map(100,0,100,40,width-40);
    yy2=map(0,0,100,height-40,40);
    line(xx1,yy1,xx2,yy2);

    strokeWeight(1);
    for(int i=1;i<21;i++)
    {
        yy2=map(i*10,0,200,height-40,40);
        yy1=yy2;
        line(xx1,yy1,xx2,yy2);
    }
    yy2=map(100,0,100,height-40,40);
    yy1=map(0,0,100,height-40,40);
    for(int i=1;i<41;i++)
    {
        xx1=map(i*5,0,200,40,width-40);
        xx2=map(i*5,0,200,40,width-40);
        line(xx1,yy1,xx2,yy2);
    }

    textAlign(RIGHT); // 100 degree
    // result+=yy1;
    fill(255);
    strokeWeight(1);
    textFont(f12);
    for(int i=-10;i<11;i++)
    {
        String result="";
        result+=5*i;
        ymargin(result, x1,y1);
        y1+=5;
    }

    x1=0;
    y1=0;
    strokeWeight(1);
    textFont(f10);
    for(int i=0;i<41;i++)
    {
        String result="";
        result+=28*3*i;
        xmargin(result, x1,y1);
        x1+=5;
    }

    textAlign(RIGHT);
    textAlign(RIGHT);
}

void ymargin(String value, int x1, int y1)
{
    float xx1=map(x1,0,100,40,width-40);
    float yy1=map(y1,0,100,height-40,40);
    text(value,xx1-5,yy1+5);
}

void xmargin(String value, int x1, int y1)
{
    float xx1=map(x1,0,200,40,width-40);
    float yy1=map(y1,0,100,height-25,25);
    text(value,xx1+7,yy1);
}

void Text(String value, int x1, int y1)
{
    float xx1=map(x1,0,100,40,width-40);
    float yy1=map(y1,0,100,height-25,25);
    text(value,xx1,yy1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see anything in your code that could be a cause for this
behavior. So maybe the cause is *outside* the code.

How do you simulate an earthquake? I guess you manually move the sensor
somehow. It may well happen that, after moving it, it doesn't settle in
exactly the same orientation it was before. When this happens, the
acceleration of gravity will be in a slightly different direction, and
your calibration will not be valid anymore. You can check for this
condition by watching the displayed values: if they settle to something
almost constant but large (more than 20 in absolute value), then that is
what is happening.

If this is the case, a possible solution would be to redo the
calibration a couple of seconds after detecting an earthquake. I would
suggest a technique that is, in my view, more elegant: calibrate
continuously, i.e. update the calibration every few microseconds.

The idea is that, instead of computing a set of offsets once and for
all, you low-pass-filter the raw readings and use these smoothed
readings as offsets. When you subtract the offsets from the readings,
you are implementing in essence a high-pass filter.

Here is a tentative implementation of this idea. I made the readings
periodic in order to have some control on the time constant of the
filter. In practice, you would have to adapt the time constant to the
requirements of your experiment:

```cpp
// Constants to be adjusted, times are in microseconds.
const uint32_t readingPeriod   = 10e3;  // 10e3 us = 10 ms
const float filterTimeConstant = 10e6;  // 10e6 us = 10 s
const float filterConstant = readingPeriod / filterTimeConstant;

// Periodically updated filtered accelerations.
float accelX, accelY, accelZ;

// Internal state of the filter.
uint32_t lastTimeReading = 0;
float offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ;

// Call this from setup()
void initializeOffsets() {
    offsetX = analogRead(x);
    offsetY = analogRead(y);
    offsetZ = analogRead(z);
}

// Call this from loop()
void updateAccelerations() {
    // Take the readings only every readingPeriod us.
    if (micros() - lastTimeReading < readingPeriod)
        return;
    lastTimeReading += readingPeriod;

    // Read the sensors.
    int readingX = analogRead(x);
    int readingY = analogRead(y);
    int readingZ = analogRead(z);

    // Update the offsets.
    offsetX += filterConstant * (readingX - offsetX);
    offsetY += filterConstant * (readingY - offsetY);
    offsetZ += filterConstant * (readingZ - offsetZ);

    // Update the filtered accelerations.
    accelX = readingX - offsetX;
    accelY = readingY - offsetY;
    accelZ = readingZ - offsetZ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: What part of my code should I put your code?

Comment: @ChristianMarasigan: It's written in the comments. Please don't just copy-paste this without understanding at least the general principle. Look at the comments. If something does not make sense, ask.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the outputs to Integers from Double and see if it's still 'ringing'.

The description suggests it is creating a feedback loop (critically damped) and you have to set a lower limit of those values that also shut the device down.

So, if you are currently reading precision of < 0.00001 ( in any axis) add a break in the program.

Big old guess but good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but is the vibration from the buzzer sufficiently strong to trigger the accelerometer? If so, once the buzzer sounds after detecting an earthquake, it might just keep triggering itself.

To fix this, you probably need to take some sample accelerometer readings to see how strong the buzzer vibrations are compared to the signal from an earthquake. You could then look to change your calibration or try to filter out the signal from the buzzer.

Alternatively, you might need to physically isolate the buzzer from the accelerometer.